# SSRS 2008 and Dynamic Positioning of Text Boxes

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I'm trying to produce a pay check. I will allow the user to setup the position of the items according to their check style.

From my research, it seems that the position of text boxes in SSRS is static and not dynamic. There is no "expression" option for Top/Left. I thought a way to get around this might be to make the text boxes large and overlapping and then set the padding top/left based on expressions to the positions that user has selected. However, it seems that similar to HTML, the text boxes either float around the higher level text boxes or simply drop out of view.

This would be simple if there were a way to tell SSRS not to be concerned with the order of the text boxes and simply display them overlapping, however I don't feel that there is.

Given that, what other options to I have for dynamically positioning text boxes in an SSRS 2008 report? I'm moving right along with this project but I've hit this stumbling block.

Answer (score 2):

SSRS gives you a lot of options for dynamic formatting but Size and Location are fixed. You cannot change this. Overlapping of textboxes does not work in the soft-break renderers like HTML and Excel but does work in hard-break renderers like PDF or TIFF. Have you tried your padding technique and output the report as PDF?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I'll give that a try to see what happens. I suppose just because the report does not render properly does not mean it may not export properly.

Comment: That does work! Thanks for the tip. I have each text box set to the same size and then adjust the padding based on values from the DB. Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are going to do in your report, But in similar cases I usually use **Space character** to position a text. For instance,

```
IIf(Len(Fields(YourColumn.valu)) > 10, Fields(YourColumn.valu), "    ")
```

Note that you have to ensure it can implemented in your case or not. I'm not sure that it is helpful but as long as the location and width properties are fix this is the only option

Note 2 : I'm using **Unbreakable Space character** instead of **simple Space** so that SSRS render it without any problem